# After generating two random numbers, print all integers between them which divisible by 5 & 8 using loop

Tags: java, while-loop

i want to generate two random numbers, lower and upper range 1-1000 and  want to write a 
program which will use while loop to print all the integers between lower (inclusive) and 
upper (inclusive) which are divisible by 5 or 8 in descending order to the console in one 
line.
Example: If i take  lower and upper numbers are 1 and 100, respectively,  output:
40 80.

Please help me with the technique.

Comment: @Ork have you tried something first?

Comment: I only can generate the random values..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea will be to generate 2 random numbers using `Math.random`.
Then you'll look for each number in-between `lowBoundary` and `highBoundary` and check if this number divisible by both 5 and 8 (e.g. `i % 5 == 0 && i % 8 == 0`) - since if the mod is 0 that means that there's no reminder from the devision.

so in general, assuming that you've collected the 2 random numbers you should have something like that:

```
for(int i = lowBoundary + 1; i < highBoundary ; i++) {
  if(i % 5 == 0 && i % 8 == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as expected. You can't declare a variable `final` and later change it.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help someone out, but this appears to be someone who has a homework assignment who has shown no effort.  The group tends to frown on such actions (on the original poster's part).